# NodeJS cannot find module 'grpc'

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi3

Im trying to run a JS script on my raspberry pi 3 but i keep returning to a problem which appears to be the "grpc" module.

i have tried reinstalling and rebulding npm following https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/442 som of the proposed answers in this thread, but i keep returning to the same error message as shown below.

Does anyone have experience with firbase running in JS on raspberry pi who know how to fix this, it appears only to be a problem when i have the connection to my firebase in the JS file.

```
    module.js:557
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'grpc'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/itPDP2018/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:10:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
```

Comment: Have you confirmed it works on your computer? If not, then you really shouldn't try to make raspberry and other unrelated things part of the problem.

Comment: i testet everything before pushing to the pi. It seems to be somekind of libary problem on the pi, but as im fairly new to the raspberry world i dont know how to fix this

Comment: Have you tried installing the newest version of firebase-tools? According to one of the comments, grpc is no longer a dependency. Do you get any errors when installing firebase-tools on the raspberry?

Comment: I reinstalled the firebase-tool with sudo acces, and then ran npm install grpc and now it works, this whas the first thing i did 8 hours ago but now it works!

Comment: Ok, I'd say you should answer your own question and accept the answer, in case anyone else ends up on this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix for me was to first remove my node_modules from the pi's libary using:

```
sudo rm -rf node_modules
```

in my project folder. 
Then reinstalling the modules with

```
npm install
```

but still the grpc module was missing, but installing it with:

```
sudo npm install grpc
```

fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The new way is this.

```sh
npm i @grpc/grpc-js
```