# Deploying to AWS without a VM, when trying to fetch anything in Firestore on non-local server { Error: Cannot find module 'grpc'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, google-cloud-firestore

I'm able to run my code successfully locally, connecting to the same firestore, but when I push my code up to my release server and hit the same endpoint, I get the following error:

```
{ Error: Cannot find module 'grpc'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:46:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/index.js:33:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

package.json `dependencies` include:

```
"firebase-admin": "^6.4.0",
"firebase-functions": "2.1.0",
```

In my `index.js`:

```
var firestore = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./firestore-config.json");
firestore.initializeApp({
  credential: firestore.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
```

In my `main.js`:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendPush", function (request, response) {
  var db = firestore.firestore();

  db.collection("myCollection")
    .doc(request.params.id)
    .get()
    .then(docSnapshot => {
       // code that never hits
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("there was some error...");

        response.error("Unable to get mute settings for group b");
        assert.ok(true);
    });
```

My code falls into the catch block as soon as I deploy. Any idea what's going on here? Thanks

Edit:

Neither my local instance nor my server are running docker, vagrant or any kind of virtual machine, npm install is done as part of the deploy process on my AWS machine

Comment: That's usually a sign that you local environment is different than the production one. Any more details on that prod environment? Does it run on a virtual machine, docker, heroku, etc...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS cannot find module 'grpc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50604566/nodejs-cannot-find-module-grpc)

Comment: Just runs on aws elastic beanstalk, no docker, vm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an answer to this after hunting around in the `firebase-admin-node` [GitHub issues](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/105#issuecomment-452418384):

I added a `.npmrc` file to my root of my project and added
`unsafe-perm=true` as the only line in the file. Deployed and it worked fine.

Core issue had to do with user permissions to install `gprc` which is detailed in the link above.